# Redmine alike application plugin system in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, plugins, redmine

I want my application users to be able to install plugin without modifying the base code (Gemfile included).

In rails 2, I used to host plugin on git server and install our plugins with `script/install https://url/to/plugin.git`, but it seems not possible with Rails 6.

My idea was to:

1. Generate an SSH key pair on the server hosting the application
2. Authorize the public part on my git server (Gitlab deploy token)
3. Let users install plugins from the UI (given the plugin URL)
4. Generate a job to `script/install` the plugin

Is there a way / library to achieve that ?
Redmine's plugin system looks solid. Is this the best way ?

Thank you

Comment: Well I was criticising Redmine's plugin system, actually.  Beacuse if you have two plugins, with a same name, and you can't control that, since it's all open-source, and one plugin called customers, another one also called customers, but doing different thing, you can't use both :) so my idea is to have some kind of plugin registry, so it's not called by name, but rather by some aliases or ID's ...

Comment: Thank for your response. In fact for me this is a implemtation detail for now. I'm looking for a library to help me manage custom application plugins. We will develop both application and plugin.